# How to run Tomcat 6 on WinXP 64 bit?

Tags: tomcat, service, windows-xp, 64-bit

Installed Tomcat 6 on WinXP 64. It installed just fine. But when I try to launch it ( from Windows Services) I get the following error : 
"Can not start an the Apache Tomcat Service on Local computer."
 error 216:0xd8

Answer (score 13):

It's well known issue.

Tomcat wrapper for windows service is compiled for 32 bits JDK.

Steps that should allow you to install Tomcat as windows service under JDK64bits.

1. Download Tomcat binary installation (zip file; exe file will not find 64 bits JDK/JRE).
2. Extract files from the archive.
3. Rename tomcat5.exe (tomcat6.exe) to tomcat5.exe.32bits to (tomcat6.exe.32bits)
4. Extract 64 bits Tomcat wrapper from tomcat5_5_64bits_wrapper.zip and rename it to tomcat5.exe (tomcat6.exe). See [details are here](http://blog.datajelly.com/company/blog/35-running-tomcat-as-a-64-bit-windows-service.html). (Update: The Bugzilla post seems to be down, but I believe an updated exe file can be found in the [Tomcat SVN Repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_16/res/procrun/amd64/)).
5. Install it as Windows service executing "service.bat install [Tomcat instance name]", where [Tomcat instance name] is optional windows service name.
6. Under certain conditions tomcat is not correctly configure service registry values. It points out itself to 32 bits version of JRE/JDK instead of 64 bits. It can be done explicitly (path to wrong JDK/JRE) or implicitly ("auto" value that imply using of JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME that point out to 32 bits version). Anyway, it's highly recommented check registry value that define which version of JDK/JRE will be used for tomcat windows service, see key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0[Tomcat instance name]\Parameters\Log\jvm and point it out to correct 64 bits JDK/JRE (e.g. jvm=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll).

Comment: Regarding #4 ["Extract 64 bits Tomcat wrapper from tomcat5_5_64bits_wrapper.zip and rename it to tomcat5.exe (tomcat6.exe)"], it would be nice to know where to get tomcat5_5_64bits_wrapper.zip. Is that something linked to in the Bugzilla issue referred to in the datajelly.com blog post? The datajelly post currently suggests the Bugzilla post is no longer available. If so, I guess the updated version of the instructions should be to download updated Tomcat exes instead from the Tomcast Repository, as described in Ed Thomas' answer here.

Comment: Instead of #4 you can download appropriate exe files from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_18/res/procrun/amd64/ as mentioned by Ed Thomas

Comment: For #4, I tried to download from the svn.apache.org/viewvc/... but I could not find out how to download the exe. It would always just show the binary content in an HTML page. To download the exe, you can use TortoiseSVN (or any SVN client) and navigate to the appropriate directory under http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html) since version 6.0.21 the 64-bit components are packaged in the native installer:

> Include 64-bit Windows service wrapper in distributions. Update the Windows installer to automatically use the correct binary on 64-bit machines. (markt)

You should need no further configuration.

Comment: I am confirming that this works as expected on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit).

Answer (score 4):

I've struggled with this. I was trying to install Tomcat 6 on a Windox XP x64 system running on a virtual Intel Xeon CPU (X5460). I used FoxyBOA's comment as a guide, but offer the following:

1. Install the Windows x64 JRE from Sun.
2. Install Tomcat 6 (I used the Windows Service Installer version), you'll have to manually point it to the JRE you downloaded during the install (just click the "..." button and find the jre6 directory).
3. Download updated versions of tomcat6.exe and tomcat6w.exe from the [Tomcat Repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_18/res/procrun/amd64/) (you may want to find the tag that matches the exact version of Tomcat you downloaded) and place these in the bin directory. I don't know why the amd64 version works on an Intel processor, [but it does](http://blogs.msdn.com/gauravseth/archive/2006/03/01/541288.aspx).

After that, everything worked: I was able to startup Tomcat with its service manager and with the Windows Service Management Console.

At the time I did this, I used Tomcat 6.0.18 and Sun Java 6 Update 12 (64-bit).

Comment: Excellent, your answer completes FoxyBOA's answer.

Comment: Following this worked perfectly to get Tomcat 6.0.24 running as a service under Windows 7 64bit. The 'monitor tomcat' application still doesn't run though - (v6.0.24 doesn't appear to have a 64bit version of this and v6.0.18 doesn't work).

Comment: This worked for me using Tomcat6.0.29 with windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 both 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and simplest way to runs Tomcat at a 64bit Windows environment is installing the 32Bit JDK. Note: You can install JDK 32Bit after been instaled the JDK 64Bit, no problems will occur and de JDK will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let folks know that when using 64bit tomcat 6, the registry to look at is

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\

Note the additional \Wow6432Node\

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Wow6432Node node is for 32 bit programs running on a 64 bit Windows, not for 64 bit programs running on a 64 bit windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify step 6 so you put it in java instead of log in the registry value

6. Under certain conditions tomcat is not correctly configure service registry values. It points out itself to 32 bits version of JRE/JDK instead of 64 bits. It can be done explicitly (path to wrong JDK/JRE) or implicitly ("auto" value that imply using of JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME that point out to 32 bits version). Anyway, it's highly recommented check registry value that define which version of JDK/JRE will be used for tomcat windows service, see key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0[Tomcat instance name]\Parameters*java*\jvm and point it out to correct 64 bits JDK/JRE (e.g. jvm=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll).

Answer (score 0):

FYI. 
I have it working now: Tomcat 6.0.29 and JRE 6u23, no mucking about - install the JRE, install Tomcat service installer, job done. It all starts up and works perfectly.