# Tomcat on Windows x64 using 32-bit JDK

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, win64

Hoping someone can help.

**The rub:**  I can't get Tomcat 5.5 to start as a windows service on 64-bit windows using a 32-bit JDK.

**the details:**
I've been running Tomcat 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 (x64) as a service for some time using a 64-bit JDK.

I'm being forced to install a 32-bit JDK on this 64-bit machine so I can make use of the Java JAI libraries (no 64-bit JAI version).  I have to run Tomcat using this 32-bit JDK.

I can run Tomcat using the 32-bit JDK if I start it using /bin/startup.bat

Problem is, it will not start as a windows service.  I'm using the Tomcat bundled procrun executables.  Has anyone had success starting Tomcat as a service using a 32-bit JDK on a 64-bit machine?

Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: I suggest that you **also** ask this question on ServerFault.  (But I do not think it should be closed!)

Comment: If you are done close it

Answer (score 3):

To run with a 64-bit JDK, you need to use tomcat.exe and tomcatw.exe that are compiled 64-bit.  To run with a 32-bit JDK, you need the .exes that are compiled 32-bit.

It is likely that the install package you got for Tomcat contained 64-bit executables. Go to the download page (http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi), download the 32-bit version and you should be fine.

This question has more info on running Tomcat with 64-bit.
[How to run Tomcat 6 on WinXP 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211446/how-to-run-tomcat-6-on-winxp-64-bit)

Comment: I don't think this answers his question.  He needs to run Tomcat on a 32bit JDK on 64bit Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Although not correct, it actually contains a key element.  I found the answer the problem.  To get it to run with the 32bit JDK, you have to use the procrun executables compiled for the 32-bit JDK (this is the default).  To get it to run with the 64-bit JDK, I replaced the 32-bit tomcat.exe with the 64-bit version (also included, but in a subfolder).

It turns out the bit depth of the OS doesn't matter here.  Just match the bit depth of the tomcat.exe with the JDK.